# How do I dispose of Xenon light bulbs?

Tags: light

I have some under-cabinet lighting that uses Xenon G8 bulbs. I didn't even know this type of light bulb existed until recently. One of the bulbs has stopped working and I want to get rid of it.

What is the right/best way to dispose of Xenon light bulbs?

Comment: The amount of material in these things is so tiny that I suspect the answer is "just throw it away". But I'd be interested to hear from anybody with evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a xenon (Xe 54) gas inside the bulb and this is inert. Does not harm anything in so tiny amount and it is environment friendly. Bigger xenon lamp should not be breached, because the pressure inside the lamp is different and this they could shatter/explode, but G8 does absolutely nothing, if that happen, but don't do it. To throw it away could be OK. Some countries have a possibility to separate electronic material waste in some disposal companies. They can handle it for you, if you feel hyper-sustainable. Read something about it here: http://renewablekinabalu.blogspot.sk/2013/04/xenon-lighing-another-environmentally.html